# Find rows that contain only zeros

Tags: matlab, matrix, rows, extract

I have a huge matrix in MATLAB. Now some rows contain only zeros.

Can I use the function `find` to find all the rows which contain *only* zeros ?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Matlab. Forgot to add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `any` to find any rows that have non-zeros and then negate the result. We use the second input to specify that we want to apply the operation across the columns (the 2nd dimension).

```
row_has_all_zeros = ~any(data, 2)
```

If you want the indices instead of the logical array, just apply `find` to the result:

```
indices = find(row_has_all_zeros);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need, you can obtain more speed (depending on your dataset) by first looking for partial zero rows (in this example length 10) and computing further with the selection of rows.

```
row_has_first10_zeros = sum(data(:,1:10),2);
row_has_all_zeros = sum(data(~rows,:),2);

indices = find(~row_has_first10_zeros)
indices = indices(~row_has_all_zeros)
```

Answer (score 0):

`n = length(matrix);`

This line will give you the number of rows in a matrix.

`ids = setdiff(1:n,find(sum(matrix,2)));`

ids will give you the row numbers(indexes) which contain only zeros.